# The type 'X' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. VS2015/aspnetcore/c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I am using rc2 aspnetcore and my project builds and runs fine if i use the command `dotnet run`, but in visual studio i get 700+ errors saying

> The type'X' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must
>   add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version 4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=netrual... '

Why is this?  Should i have to add the reference of System.Runtime to my project.json file in order for VS2015 not to throw these exceptions upon building?

I am using dotnet cli version 1.0.0-preview2-002913 to run my code.

Comment: What frameworks do you target?

Comment: @Marcus i am targeting net451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add System.Runtime to "frameworkAssemblies" to your `project.json`:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {
        "frameworkAssemblies": {
            "System.Runtime": "4.0.10.0"
        }
    },
```